# Doubles aren't comparing

Tags: equals, decimalformat

I have a quiz grader assignment, it has to be read from a txt file and I've tried all the possible combinations that I have in knowledge. When I run the program, the last question is "What is the square root of 2?" I type 1.41 (Which is the right answer and I also so formatted the answer to 2 decimal points) and the program says that the answer is not correct.

this is my code

Public Class quiz;

```
 public void read(Scanner in) {
    questionList = new ArrayList<>();
    Question qu = new Question();
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        double num;
        type = in.nextLine();
        question = in.nextLine();

        switch (type) {
            case "N":
                num = Double.parseDouble(in.nextLine());
                qu = new Question(type, question, num); 
                break;
        }
        questionList.add(qu);
    }
}

public ArrayList<Question> getQuestions() {
    return questionList;
}

public boolean[] checkAnswers(ArrayList<String> answers) {
    boolean[] quizAnswers = new boolean[questionList.size()];
    char ch;
    for (int i = 0; i < questionList.size() - 1; i++) {
        Question qu = questionList.get(i);
        ch = qu.getMyType().charAt(0);

else if (ch == 'N') {             
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
                    double quizNumAnswer = qu.getMyNumAnswer();
                    String formattedAnswer = df.format(quizNumAnswer);
                    System.out.println(formattedAnswer);
                    if(answers.get(i).equals(formattedAnswer))
                        quizAnswers[i] = true;
                    else
                        quizAnswers[i] = false;    
            }

return quizAnswers;
    }
}
```

Public Class Questions;

```
private String typeOfQuestion;
private String quizQuestion;
private double myNumAnswer;

public Question(String type, String question, double numAnswer) {
    typeOfQuestion = type;
    quizQuestion = question;
    myNumAnswer = numAnswer;
}

public String getMyType() {
    return typeOfQuestion;
}

public double getMyNumAnswer() {
    return myNumAnswer;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    char ch = typeOfQuestion.charAt(0);
    switch (ch) {
        case 'N':
            return typeOfQuestion + " " + quizQuestion;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getText() {
    return toString();
}

public String getAnswer() {
    char ch = typeOfQuestion.charAt(0);
    String answer = null;
    switch (ch) {

        case 'N':
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
            String stringAnswer = df.format(myNumAnswer);
            answer = stringAnswer;
            break;
    }
    return answer;
}
```

My output

What is the square root of 2?

Correct answer: 1.41

Your answer: 1.41

Your answer was not correct.

How would I be able to compare them and get the right answer, need some clues!

Comment: sqrt(2) is not 1.41. It is also irrational and therefore cannot be represented in floating point.

Comment: Even rationals such as 1/5 can't be represented in floating point.

Comment: @bathsheba like I said, I'm reading in from a text file.  The text file read "1.41421356" so I cut it off to 1.41

Comment: It seems you are comparing two string, why not put a break point in the line 'if(answers.get(i).equals(formattedAnswer))' to debug the program?